# Any way to group pseudo selectors in Tailwind?

Tags: html, tailwind-css

Is it possible to group `pseudo selectors` in tailwind?

For example transform this:

```
<div class="before:w-5 before:h-5">hello world</div>
```

to something like:

```
<div class="before:[w-5 h-5]">hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I was really interested in the answer to your question. I definitely think it would be a great feature to have this kind of functionality. I tried reaching Tailwind's discord server, and I opened a thread asking this question. This is the answer I received:

[image: Wongjn's answer]

> The Tailwind maintainers did look at this feature at one point but ultimately decided to put it on hold for now. See this Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1461519820411789314

So, as you can see from the answer and the Twitter feed, it's currently on hold. In the Twitter thread, the developers were testing this feature regarding performance, and it looks like this feature, at its current state duplicates CSS compared to using individual utilities:

> So we did a test where we converted every single Tailwind UI template (over 500 files) to use the grouped syntax to see how much bandwidth grouping would save you when serving HTML.

> This makes sense when you think about it, because using the grouped syntax (like `focus:(font-bold,underline)`) leads to *fewer* repeated symbols in the document, because there are now more unique class names.

> Using the non-grouped syntax, every instance of `focus:font-bold` can be compressed out and replaced with a short placeholder (say %).
> Using grouped syntax, `focus:font-bold` and `focus:(font-bold,underline)` *can't* be compressed out, because they are no longer the same.
> Plot twist: After compression, the files are actually *bigger*, not smaller!

#### Bottom line:

> So the takeaway here is that although the grouped syntax *looks* like less code when you're authoring it, it actually creates both a bigger CSS file *and* a bigger HTML file in production, making it a very black and white performance anti-pattern.

> It's nicer to write though, and the performance cost isn't a huge one, so still a chance we develop it further just for the developer experience for the people who like it. But admittedly hesitant to encourage anything that's bad for performance.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Let's hope they decide to implement it. I don't understand why they just can't namespace-wrap all classes with the corresponding pseudo class togethere and compile it into something that resembles the same tailwind code as writning them out by hand.

Comment: I think their argument is silly. They can simply separate all variant classes first. For example for `hover:(bg-red-800 text-white)` they can improve their compiler for converting it to `hover:bg-red-800 hover:text-white` first, and then compile it. I failed to understand why they didn't do that.