# Looking for a way to beat repetitive tailwindCSS Pseud typing like dark:

Tags: tailwind-css

As title says i just start using tailwindcss and i can't find away yet for this issue
So is there away to group up for example all dark mode option instead of typing `dark: or hover:` for every utility that needs to be changed

**Edit:** code to clear question
you need to do something like this for example for dark mode

```css
class='dark:text-white dark:bg-red dark:hover:text-blue dark:focus:bg-yellow'
```

what i wonder about is there away to group or nest this somthing like

```css
dark:[text-white,bg-red]....
```

or like scss way

```css
dark:text-white 
& bg-red
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: edited post hopefully its more clear now sorry

Comment: This question got asked yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74166688/any-way-to-group-pseudo-selectors-in-tailwind/74170922#74170922). I posted an answer with the current state of this feature including the developer's updates :)